# Is it possible to create a global Chromium extension which will update itself automatically?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium, browser-extension, opera-extension

We create extensions for Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Internet Explorer. We don't have an extension for Opera (yet), but I noticed that if I install the .crx file in Opera, everything works the same as in Chrome. I would like to know if we can create a global Chromium extension that will work in any Chromium browser (including Opera and Chrome), and how do I do it? I want our extension to update itself every time we release a new version, and it does in Chrome (and also Firefox and Safari), how do we do the same with Opera and all the other Chromium browsers (browsers based on Chromium) or do we have to release a different extension for every browser separately? Do we have to create a separate version for Opera or can we create one extension for all Chromium browsers?

Comment: Can Chromium browsers install extensions directly from Chrome Web Store? Same with Opera.

Comment: @Xan I don't think so, Chrome Web Store is only for Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to distribute an extension to Google Chrome (and Chromium) is to place it in the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore). Opera has a similar site for [add-ons](https://addons.opera.com/). Both offer automatic updates when you upload a new version. Even if you use the same code for both browsers you need to distribute it through separate channels.

Comment: How can I distribute extensions for Chromium browsers which are not Chrome and Opera?

Comment: Plain Chromium can still access the Chrome Web Store. I don't know about other Chromium-based browsers. It is up to the developers of each.